# PDFBox: How to detect the max length of a PDTextBox

Tags: pdfbox

I'm working with an AcroForm which has a text field (PDTextBox) with a max length. How do I use PDFBox to detect the max length of this field.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a

```
PDTextbox field
```

you can retrieve the Dictionary modelling the text box using

```
COSDictionary fieldDict = field.getDictionary()
```

and query its properties here.

The dictionary entry for the maximum length is **MaxLen**:

> **MaxLen** integer *(Optional; inheritable)* The maximum length of the field’s text, in characters
>
> *(Table 229 in [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), the PDF standard)*

Thus:

```
int maxLength = fieldDict.getInt(COSName.getPDFName("MaxLen"));
```

If this returns `-1`, though, the value is not set in this dictionary. As the value is specified as *inheritable*, you may also have to retrieve the parent dictionaries

```
COSDictionary parentDict = (COSDictionary) fieldDict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.PARENT);
```

and look for the key in there. Probably you have to step up multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this as solution:

```
int maxLength = field.getCOSObject().getInt(COSName.MAX_LEN);
```

Given that the field's maximum length is set manually in a form created in OpenOffice, and exported as a PDF, that maximum length can then be retrieved in Java code using the solution above. If the maximum length is not set then -1 is returned.

Note that using pdfbox 2.0.1 the code in the accepted answer gave me syntax errors in Eclipse:

```
codeCOSDictionary fieldDict = field.getDictionary();

int maxLength = fieldDict.getInt(COSName.getPDFName("MaxLen"));
```

Comment: Yes, in 2.0 getDictionary() was removed and getCOSObject() now returns the appropriate type.

Comment: In 2.x you now also have `PDTextField.getMaxLen()`